# Is Prüfer group a module over the ring of $p$-adic integers?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let $p$ be a prime number. Let $$\mathbb{Z}_{p}=\left\{\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_ip^i\mid a_i\in \{0,1,2,\dots,p-1\}\right\}$$ and $$\mathbb{Z}_{p^\infty}=\left\{ \frac{a}{p^n}+\mathbb{Z}\mid a\in \mathbb{Z}\text{ and }n\in \mathbb{N}\right\}$$
denote the ring of $p$-adic integers and Prüfer $p$-group, respectively.

In the book: "Nguyen, V.D., Dinh, V.H., Smith, P.F., Wisbauer, R.: *Extending Modules*, Pitman Research Notes in Mathematics Series, vol. 313. Longman Scientific and Technical (1994)" at page number 179, it is written that $\mathbb{Z}_{p^\infty}$ is a $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$-module.

Since elements of $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ have an infinite sum, how can we define external binary operation (in terms of above definition of ring)?

Comment: We have $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}=\{\displaystyle\frac{a}{b}|a,b\in\mathbb{Z},p\nmid b\}$, which is the $p$-localization of $\Bbb Z$. It is not the ring of $p$-adic integers. So please clarify the title.

Comment: Though, my notation is different, but the set given by me represent the set of p-adic integers. Here, you can see it. T https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/527052/ring-of-p-adic-integers-mathbb-z-p  If there is confusion, I will change my notation. Actually, I have used notation from the book cited in the Question.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I said. But you wrote $\Bbb Z_{(p)}$ in the text instead of $\Bbb Z_p$ in your first sentence and two times more again later. So I guess we have two different questions, really. So: $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$-module, or $\Bbb Z_p$-module? Of course, $\Bbb Z_{(p)}\hookrightarrow \Bbb Z_p$.

Comment: Yes. I mean $\mathbb{Z}_p$-module.

Comment: I see, very good. You can use the definition of $\Bbb Z_p$ by an inverse limit  of finite rings to see the module action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More generally, let $A$ be any abelian group such that the order of any element is a power $p$, then $A$ can be given a (unique) $\Bbb Z_p$-module structure as follows: Let $a \in A$ of order $p^n$ and let $\lambda \in \Bbb Z_p$. Then we can take the projection $\pi_n:\Bbb Z_p \to \Bbb Z/p^n\Bbb Z$ and simply define $\lambda a = \pi_n(\lambda)a$ (since $a$ is of order $p^n$, it makes sense to multiply it by a scalar from $\Bbb Z/p^n\Bbb Z$.) If we write $\lambda = \displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^\infty a_ip^i$, then this definition just means that we define $\lambda a$ to be $\left(\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_ip^i\right)a$. This definition is quite intuitive. Indeed we know that $p^ia=0$ for $i \geq n$, so if we want to define what $\left(\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_ip^i\right)a$ is supposed to be, then since $p^ia=0$ for $i \geq n$, a natural choice would be to throw away all the terms $a_ip^i$ for $i \geq n$ from our infinite sum, but then we are just left with the finite sum $\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_ip^i$, which is an ordinary integer and we know how to multiply an element by that.

(In a similar fashion, one can show that every torsion group has a $\widehat{\Bbb Z}$-module structure)